# Shell Script error unexpected else token

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I am using below code to read records from one file and comparing its 6 field with other file and accordingly writing the output to the files.

```
for FILE_NAME in `GET_FILE_LIST $1 $2 $3`
do
y=`echo $FILE_NAME|awk '{print $6}'`"X"
echo "Start --- `date`" >> $LOGF
echo $y >> $LOGF
cat $x |nawk ' BEGIN { FS=",";
while ((getline < "SUBNO.txt") > 0)
     myarray[$1] = $2
if(myarray[$6]==0)   
    ' > {${FILE_NAME}_P}
else
    ' > {${FILE_NAME}_S}
fi

UPD_FILE_STATUS $FILE_NAME 35
done
```

The issue is I am geeting following error:

```
./TEST.sh: line 95: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
./TEST.sh: line 95: `else'
```

I have following case:
In one text file I have data like this:

```
GGO     099E7C5S    34  533196588       45696   22
PPC     93403DSA    35  784397429       44696   56
```

In the second file data is like this:

```
22,0
24,1
26,0
```

What I want to do is write line from first file, compare the last field value with second file.If it is value is 0 put it in new file_1 and if it is 1 then put it in file_2.
I hope this will clear the case.
Please help.

Comment: What is the purpose of the backticks ?

Comment: is `else` a part of the awk script?

Comment: Do u think these are causing problem? I am bit new to this

Comment: A wonderful candidate for _The most horrible bash mistakes and bad practices_. (I know this comment is not helpful at first sight).

Comment: Your script is such a mess that it's impossible to say what's going on. Rewrite your question. Tell us what the script is suppose to be doing, what your data looks like, and what you want to print out. Awk scripts need to be surrounded with curly braces, and yours isn't. Awk scripts' `BEGIN` clause should have it's own curly braces, and you're doesn't have a closing one. It's impossible to even analyze what you want. Tell us, and maybe we can help clean up the mess.

Comment: Is this the section containing line 95? If so your conditional needs white space: `if (myarray[$6]==0)`

Comment: Thnx dear for bearing and replying. I have added more information.

Comment: @QMG All but 2 lines of your script (`do` and `done`) have at least one error on them. Would you like help to re-write it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you updated your question to say you wanted (split file1 based on info from file2)

```
awk 'NR==FNR{sfx[$1]=$2; next} {print > ("file_" sfx[$NF]+0)}' FS="," file2 FS=" " file1
```

You didn't say what to do with lines from file1 when the last field on the line has no entry in file2 so my script treats it the same as if there was a 0-ending entry in file2. If that's not what you want, it's an easy fix.

Answer (score 1):

There are a *lot* of bad practices in this script which I will not address here.  The problem you have is that you seem confused about quoting rules.  Consider the code:

```
cat $x |nawk ' BEGIN { FS=",";
while ((getline < "SUBNO.txt") > 0)
     myarray[$1] = $2
if(myarray[$6]==0)   
    ' > {${FILE_NAME}_P}
else
```

The single quotes delimit the script that is passed to `nawk`, so the above snippet is essentially equal to:

```
cat $x | nawk cmds > {${FILE_NAME}_P}
else
```

The colorization of your editor (and even in the question's display here on SO) should make this clear.  You will notice that the `else` does not have a matching if, so the shell treats that as a syntax error.

Please note that you are redirecting to a file named `{xxx_P}`.  It is unusual to put `{` and `}` characters in a filename.

Answer (score 0):

The following will extract from file2 all lines whose sixth field is present with a ",0" suffix in file1. It does this by transforming the relevant lines from file1 into a simple awk script. Repeat with the ",1" suffix to get the other set, or learn enough awk to do it all in a single pass; it's not hard.

```
sed /,0$/!d;s///;s/.*/$6 == "&"/p' file1 |
awk -f - file2
```

The sed script is somewhat obscure; it deletes any non-matching lines, then replaces the matching suffix with nothing, then wraps the remainder with a suitable awk condition.

Depending on taste and requirements, you could make the second script a sed script instead (hint: look for the w command) or the first script an awk script as well.